# How can I use a contructor on an Entity that has properties with @ManyToOne decorator without passing instances of other entities and only their ids?

Tags: nestjs, mikro-orm

how can I use a constructor on an Entity that has properties with **@ManyToOne** decorator and their types are from another Entity but only with the primary key.
For example:

```
@Entity()
class User {
  constructor(
    idUser: number,
    idExtraData: number
  ){
    this.id = idUser;
    // this is going to give an error because it requires an instance of ExtraData.
    // but I would like to pass only the id
    // and have an instance similar when I use findOne without populating anything
    this.extraData = idExtraData;
  }

  @PrimaryKey()
  id: number;

  @ManyToOne()
  extraData: ExtraData;

}
```

The instance of the entity I want should be similar to the instance returned by findOne without populating anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Reference.createNakedFromPK()`

```
@Entity()
export class Book {

  @ManyToOne(() => Author)
  author: Author;

  constructor(authorId: number) {
    this.author = Reference.createNakedFromPK(Author, authorId);
  }

}
```

This instance will be either replaced with the managed entity during flush if there is one, or it will be merged to the EM otherwise.

(the docs mention how to do this with reference wrapper only, but its the same approach)

https://mikro-orm.io/docs/entity-references#assigning-to-reference-properties